# Cannot call state from redux in react-pdf component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-pdf

i am trying to firgure out how to use this react-pdf lib in my project. At first I tried to render the state directly from redux store into a react-pdf component  and it didn't worked.

It shows the Error:

```
could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>
```

I have many other components which have used the state from redux and none of them have this problem until I tried to render a component from react-pdf within  and .

Here is a part of my code:

```
const ConfigurationListPdf = (props)=> {
    const mech = useSelector(mechConfig);
    return(
            <>
                <Document>
                    <Page size="A4" style={styles.page}>
                        <View style={styles.section}>
                            <Text>
                                {props.elem}
                            </Text>
                        </View>
                    </Page>
                </Document>
            </>
        )
}

export default function InfoBoard(){
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        page: {
            flexDirection: 'row',
        },
        section: {
            margin: 10,
            padding: 10,
            flexGrow: 1
        }
    });

// Create Document Component
    return(
        <>
            <CntrInfoBoard>
                <InnerBoard>
                    <TitelDiv>
                    <Typography variant="h5" sx{{color:'white',fontWeight:900}}>Summary</Typography>
                    </TitelDiv>
                    <CntrInfoDetails>
                        <NodeTable/>
                    </CntrInfoDetails>
                    <Terms>
                        <p>
                            xxx
                        </p>
                    </Terms>
                    <PDFViewer>
                        <ConfigurationListPdf />
                    </PDFViewer>
                    <CntrSaveBtn>
                        <BtnSave>Configuration save</BtnSave>
                        <BtnOther>Sign up to finish</BtnOther>
                        <BtnOther onClick={savePdfHandler}>
                            {/*Save to PDF*/}
                            <PDFDownloadLinkStyled
                                document={<ConfigurationListPdf/>}
                                fileName="example.pdf"
                            >
                                Download PDF
                            </PDFDownloadLinkStyled>
                        </BtnOther>
                    </CntrSaveBtn>
                </InnerBoard>
            </CntrInfoBoard>
        </>
    )
}
```

Sorry if there is a problem with the code formatting.

As long as I add a useSelector or useDispatch it shows the error.

This is weird because the  has already been wrapped in my index.js:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App/>
        </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

I thought my redux store has a problem so I tried to call state and reducers in other components without react-pdf and turns out that's not the case. They work fine.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into similar issues when trying to render PDF content. I believe the issue is that the [`PDFViewer`](https://react-pdf.org/components#pdfviewer) and [`PDFDownloadLink`](https://react-pdf.org/components#pdfdownloadlink) components render `iframe` elements and so the React components under them are likely rendered into separate sub-ReactTrees from your app context that has the Redux provider.

To get around this access the Redux state from higher in the ReactTree than either of `PDFViewer` and `PDFDownloadLink`, e.g. in the `InfoBoard` component, and pass down the selected state as props to the `ConfigurationListPdf` component.

Example:

```
const ConfigurationListPdf = ({ elem, mech })=> {
  // use mech prop now

  return (
    <Document>
      <Page size="A4" style={styles.page}>
        <View style={styles.section}>
          <Text>
            {elem}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </Page>
    </Document>
  );
}
```

```
export default function InfoBoard() {
  const mech = useSelector(mechConfig); // <-- select from Redux in parent

  // Create Document Component
  return (
    <>
      <CntrInfoBoard>
        <InnerBoard>
          ....
          <PDFViewer>
            <ConfigurationListPdf mech={mech} /> // <-- pass mech as prop
          </PDFViewer>
          <CntrSaveBtn>
            <BtnSave>Configuration save</BtnSave>
            <BtnOther>Sign up to finish</BtnOther>
            <BtnOther onClick={savePdfHandler}>
              {/*Save to PDF*/}
              <PDFDownloadLinkStyled
                document={(
                  <ConfigurationListPdf
                    mech={mech} // <-- pass mech as prop
                  />
                )}
                fileName="example.pdf"
              >
                Download PDF
              </PDFDownloadLinkStyled>
            </BtnOther>
          </CntrSaveBtn>
        </InnerBoard>
      </CntrInfoBoard>
    </>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  section: {
    margin: 10,
    padding: 10,
    flexGrow: 1
  }
});
```

Comment: I searched through the online doc from react-pdf but find nothing about topic whether the PDFViewer is rendered besides the component tree. But your solution does solved it. Thanks a lot!